# What exactly do we link (non-C) object code against?

Tags: assembly, linker, nasm, static-linking

I am new to x86 assembly. I have this simple helloworld program written in x86 assembly using nasm assembler syntax:

```
global _start

section .text:
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msglen
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data:
    msg: db "Hello World!", 0x0A
    msglen equ $-msg
```

After assembly using:

```
nasm -f elf32 helloworld.asm
```

what exactly am I linking the resulting oobject code `helloworld.o` against when I run:

```
ld -m elf_i386 helloworld.o
```

? I understand that when I compile a C program, the linking is against the C standard libraries (libc). What about here ?

Comment: Nothing. All the linker is doing is turning your object into an executable by assigning addresses. Of course you can link to whatever libraries or modules you need. After it's assembled it's just an object file. You can for example invoke the C library functions from assembly and then you'd link to the C library.

Comment: @Jester Can you write this as answer?